# Automatically create a new page with ACF repeater field

Tags: php, wordpress, post, advanced-custom-fields

I've used repeater field to create news headlines and I want to create automatically a new page for every headline. I've seen some posts about using `acf/save_post` and `wp_insert_post()` but I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: Acf has an website with all this documentation.  https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/    , and if i understand correctly you wil have to create an new page @via wordpress and link those headlines to these pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook into the [acf/save_post](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/) action to create a new post with the [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) method. But i dont understand why you want to do that. ACF is for feeding custom fields related to a post or page and should not be used to create post or pages.